# Bespoke loss routine for Keras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to implement a bespoke loss calculation model but keep getting hit with recognition failures. eg: "`ValueError: Unknown loss function: root_mean_squared_error_fraction. Please ensure this object is passed to the` custom_objects `argument.`"
The function "root_mean_squared_fraction" exists and is functioning, I know this because I call it elsewhere outside of the Keras model and it functions as expected. I'm clearly not understanding something about injecting this into the model definition and would appreciate any advice? Thanks.

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import backend as K  
def root_mean_squared_error_fraction(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square((y_pred - y_true)/y_true)))
```

This is my model routine which does work when the =rmsef in the model.compile is replaced with ='mse':

```
def ResModel(Svect, Xvect, Yvect, dtrain):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu',\
                   input_shape=(Xvect.shape[1], Xvect.shape[2]),\
                   return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(Yvect.shape[1]))
    rmsef = root_mean_squared_error_fraction
    model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = rmsef )
    bmfile = 'bestmodel.h5'
    earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='auto',\
                              verbose=0, patience=mpat, min_delta=0.005)
    chkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(bmfile, monitor = 'val_loss', mode = 'auto',\
                               save_best_only = True )
    history = model.fit(Xvect, Yvect, epochs=mcycl, batch_size=32,\
                        validation_split=dsplit, verbose=0,\
                        callbacks = [earlystop, chkpoint] )
    saved = load_model('bestmodel.h5')        
    score = saved.evaluate(Xvect, Yvect, verbose=0)
    print("Epoch: %04d yeilded best fit with overall loss of: %0.4f "\
          % ((earlystop.stopped_epoch + 1),  score  ) )       
    Yvect = descalevector(Svect, saved.predict(Xvect),dtrain )
    return Yvect, score
```

Comment: Are you creating a new model with this loss function or loading a model?

Comment: Check if everything related to your code is properly formatted. I'm trying to help you get your question answered.

Comment: Done thanks, sorry new to this and finding my way a bit with the site formats.

Comment: Still scratching my head on this one, looking yet again at the error log the very first part of the message reads:    "ValueError: Unknown loss function: RMSEF_fn. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details. "   I'm struggling to interpret the action it is trying to advise, is it perhaps saying I need to add a parameter something like :  ", custom_objects={'loss': RMSEF_fn}"  but I can not see where this would go or fit. Appreciate any thoughts or pointers, thanks.

Comment: Some further diagnostics if it helps anybody to advise me: I had deceived myself into thinking the failure was in the Model.Fit step, it is not; the Fit completes correctly after 35 or so Epoch's so clearly as far as fitting is concerned the custom loss routine is being found and used. The failure is in the load_model line below; I have tried modifying this line to read  "   saved = load_model('bestmodel.h5', custom_objects={'loss': root_mean_squared_error_fraction})   "; the Python interpreter does not object but it does not resolve the problem.  Appreciate any thoughts.